# Jekyll: Alternate Class in For Loop

Tags: for-loop, jekyll, cycle

I was wondering if there was a way to alternate between classes in a for loop.

At the moment, I'm repeating my `<article>` block, and adding a `.clearfix`
 div after the second `<article>`.

```
{% for post in site.posts %}
  {% capture thecycle %}{% cycle 'odd', 'even' %}{% endcapture %}
  {% if thecycle == 'odd' %}
    <article class="md-col-5">
      ...
    </article>
  {% else %}
    <article class="md-col-5 md-col-offset-2">
      ...
    </article>
    <div class="clearfix"></div>
  {% endif %}
{% endfor %}
```

Is there a better way to handle this, so I don't have to repeat code and so there's only one `.clearfix` div when this is outputted to HTML.

I'd prefer the output to look like this:

```
<article class="md-col-5"></article>

<article class="md-col-5 md-col-offset-2"></article>

<div class="clearfix"></div>

<article class="md-col-5"></article>

<article class="md-col-5 md-col-offset-2"></article>
```

Is this possible with Jekyll?

Any help is appreciated. Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You don't need to actually check for `even` or `odd`, you could use the `cycle`-helper to actually assign the additional class if needed. Also, you can check that string and only add the clearfix if needed:

```
{% for post in site.posts %}
    {% capture thecycle %}{% cycle 'md-col-offset-2', '' %}{% endcapture %}

    <article class="md-col-5 {{ thecycle }}">
        ...
    </article>

    {% if thecycle == 'md-col-offset-2' %}
        <div class="clearfix"></div>
    {% endif %}
{% endfor %}
```

Comment: This is a great solution. There are a total of 4 posts, is there a way to not have the second `.clearfix` after the fourth post?

Comment: Sure. You can use `{% if thecycle == 'md-col-offset-2' and forloop.last == false %}` to skip the clearfix if it is the last iteration.

Comment: Great logic. Thanks for such a great solution!